# Plugin my computer speakers directly to the monitor or onboard soundcard?

Tags: audio, motherboard, speakers, sound-card

I've just finish building my first computer and all works great! I do have a question about my computer speakers.

I've connected my computer speakers using the 3.5mm cable to my Ultrasharp DELL U2715H monitor and the sound works. But, i was wondering if i should instead connect my computer speakers to the motherboard soundcard. I have the gigabyte GA-Z170-HD3P (http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5495#sp)

What are, if any, the advantages/disadvantages on plugin my computer speakers directly to the monitor?

Comment: Presumably your monitor is connected by HDMI (and that is how it's getting the audio signal)? Probably no advantage/disadvantage either way, unless you had a high-quality soundcard and wanted to use its DAC output.  The proper way to test this is to use your ears, and listen for yourself if you can hear a difference in each configuration.

Comment: IMO, the cables would be my biggest concern - I'd use whatever resulted in a cleaner installation.

Comment: I would say that connecting to the back panel of the motherboard is probably better. I don't think the DAC in the monitor could be better.